# Comparing parts of a date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to compare two dates and do things if one date has a greater month or year than the other.

I'm not sure how to cut a date down, so I figured I'd make both dates into a string and compare certain characters of each string, but I am not finding success.
Is there a better way?

Code:

```
'Compare months

If Date1.chars(1,2) > Date.chars(1,2) Then

...

'Compare years

Else If Date1.chars(6,7,8,9) > Date.chars(6,7,8,9) Then

...

End If
```

Comment: Why break it? Why not a direct comparison? `If Date1 > Date2 Then` unless Year doesn't matter and you want to do a month comparison?

Answer (score 2):

`Dates` have underlying numeric representation in Excel Worksheet, so just use "`>`" operator between cells containing `Dates`. Example:

```
A           B           C 
6/4/2015    6/3/2015    TRUE
```

where cells `A1` and `B1` contain Dates to compare and cell `C1` contains simple Worksheet formula: `=(A1>A2)` returning "`TRUE`" if Date in `A1` is bigger than `B1`.

If you need to compare just certain `Date` parts (e.g. Month, Year, Day), then use the following Worksheet formula:

```
6/4/2015    5/4/2015    TRUE
```

where cell `C1` contains Worksheet formula : `=(=MONTH(A1)>MONTH(B1))`

Similar technique can be implemented in Excel VBA custom function (in case you need it). Hope this may help.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `Month` and `Year` functions.

```
If Month(Date1) > Month(date) then
    ...
ElseIf Year(Date1) > Year(date) then
    ...
End If
```